# My "Sun up" circuit is malfunctioning in circuit, but works fine on USB test bench

Tags: arduino, power, sensor, light

I am trying to build a circuit to use the Arduino Uno R3 as a switch for a relay which makes a connection only during daylight.

I don't know much about my LDR, pretty sure it is a 10K. I am dividing it with a 10K resister for A0 input on the Uno.

The circuit works on the bench with USB power, however when I apply 12 volts for the Uno externally, and this is also the 12 volts for the electrical equipment which is being switched by the relay, suddenly it does not work and I cannot figure out why.

I will provide a schematic. Bear in mind TinyCad does not provide me a schematic for the UNO and I am not going to use CircuitLab, so I will just mark inputs and outputs on the Arduino Mega schematic as though it were the Arduino Uno for my schematic. Hopefully this doesn't make it too difficult to understand.

The photoresistor symbol is a photodiode symbol because they did not have an LDR symbol.

The relay at 1050 ohms on 5 Volts draws only 4 ma and some change, so I did not see a need for a resistor there considering the Uno can supply up to 20ma. It is a reed relay with a high resistance coil.

I wanted to use pin 13 with the indicator LED as a built in indicator of when the relay was closed so I set it up as a separate pin which works at the same time as pin 12 because the relay is silent. I suspect it is just a magnetic reed switch with a coil somewhere to activate it so it does not click.  This way I know whether things are working or not.

My code is very simple for the Arduino:

```
const int relayPin = 12;
const int ledPin = 13;
const int ldrPin = A0;
void setup() {
 
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);

  if (ldrStatus >= 700)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH);
    

  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW);
}
}
```

As I say it works perfectly on the test bench on USB, however it stays on all the time on the other circuit with 12 volt power. The relay stays on also at all times.

Do I have a bad Uno, or do you see something I might have missed?

I have also tried changing  "if (ldrStatus >= 700)"  to different values. That also works on the bench on USB, but stays on constantly on 12 volts.

I am at a loss for words at this point. This was supposed to be a simple sun up detector to get automation going, but I am hitting my head on a brick wall here.

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: The relay pin is never set to output, is that why it does not work?

Comment: You are right but I realized that afterword, corrected it and it is still not working.  I tried a different board, same problem.  So it is not the board.  Could the length of wire to the LDR make a difference at all? maybe interference or something in the wires from RF or something?

Comment: Have you tried to print out the analogread values, or otherwise debug the hardware or software somehow, like using a multimeter to see if voltages are correct an there is no loose wires or bad soldering etc?

Comment: I am doing that now, but I am thinking there is some kind of power issue or interference out on the circuit because I am seeing no problems at all in here at the test bench.  I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: @PS85Gaming:  While you are working on it, get out your multimeter and measure the voltage on the 3V3 pin when connected to USB and when connected to the 12V supply.  If you have access to an oscilloscope, it would be good to take a look at the signal going to AIN0.

Comment: Um.. The Voltage for the Barrel Jack should not ever be more than 12 Volts right?  Is that maximum on the Uno R3?  Cause I just discovered that without a load my 12 Volt power supply on the external circuit is sitting at 16.7 Volts for some reason.  I am really surprised I have a board at all at this point.  or 2 boards actually.. This may be what is causing this weird malfunction.

Comment: You need a flywheel diode on the relay or it will kill the pin / mcu (perhaps already has).

Comment: From the [Arduino UNO R3 datatsheet,](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1682209.pdf) the recommended Vin range is "7 to 12V" while the input voltage **limit** is 6V to 20V.  You should be OK with your 17V power supply.

Comment: So I am going to be contacting a company about the PSU that is way high for what it is supposed to be on Voltage.  Both of my Arduinos are fine as far as I can tell..  I got out my bench power supply and set it to 12V and tested it inside, everything worked fine.  It's the Voltage it is too high outside on the external circuit.

Comment: Oh I completely forgot about the Diode!  Ouch Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: I doubt it is the voltage.  It is more likely interference from a poorly filtered power supply.

Comment: You're sampling the input at probably a few thousand times a second. The relay cannot react that fast. I'd suggest you add code to filter the input - this is good practice anyway and limit how fast you sample/respond to the input. You might want to add some hysteresis as well.

Comment: What if I set it to sample the LDR only once every say 2-3 minutes instead on Const or even put a delay between the If/else say 1000MS? Maybe that would help.. It almost seems like the relay cannot handle it's almost PWM at this point it is getting.  IDK

Comment: Oh Okay now we have a worse problem.  I am just going to have to run the Arduino off of a separate source.. This is ridiculous, the other circuit is drawing so much current in parallel with the Arduino that it puts a high enough resistance on the input voltage to basically make it shut off.  I am going to try a few capacitors, but I am going to make a power supply for it, this is getting out of hand.. it was supposed to be so simple yet it turned into a monster on me.

Comment: Nope I just basically made a slow oscillator with an Arduino at the power supply, not enough Amps in the Power supply already and with the Arduino using the least of everything it gets basically bypassed.. Capacitors just make it wait long enough for the other circuit to confirm power, start up, and then it throws out the Arduino, turning off the power to it and then starts over.  Not enough Amps..

Answer (score 0):

> What if I set it to sample the LDR only once every say 2-3 minutes

No! You're dealing with high frequency interference. You need to filter in both analog and digital domains.

1. Add a capacitor across the resistor between AIN and GND.
2. Sample as fast as you can, and average the results using e.g. a simple IIR filter. Say:

   ```
   y = 63/64 * y + 1/64 * input
   ```

   That can be implemented in as follows:

   ```
   y = (63*y + input)/64
   ```

You'll also likely want some hysteresis, so that the `y` relay won't be flipping back-and-forth fast.

The IIR can be calculated using scaled fixed point

```
constexpr int relayPin = 12;
constexpr int ledPin = 13;
constexpr int ldrPin = A0;

// Configurable values
constexpr auto cfg_ldr_full_scale = 1023U; // The maximum unsigned output from the ADC
constexpr auto cfg_threshold  = 0.68;      // The threshold from "off" to "on", as a fraction of full scale
constexpr auto cfg_hysteresis = 0.01;      // The hysteresis, as a fraction of full scale
constexpr auto cfg_IIR_ratio = 0.01;       // IIR update fraction of new value.
// 1.0 - zero time constant, no filtering,
// 0.0 -infinitely long filter time constant
// End of Configurable Values

constexpr uint32_t IIR_full_scale = 0x8000;
constexpr uint32_t IIR_one = 0x8000;
constexpr uint32_t IIR_new = uint32_t(IIR_one * cfg_IIR_ratio) * uint32_t(IIR_full_scale / cfg_ldr_full_scale);
constexpr uint32_t IIR_old = IIR_one - uint32_t(IIR_one * cfg_IIR_ratio);

constexpr uint32_t threshold = IIR_full_scale * cfg_threshold;
constexpr uint32_t hysteresis = IIR_full_scale * cfg_hysteresis;

constexpr uint32_t threshold_with_hyst[2] =
{ threshold - hysteresis, threshold + hysteresis };

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  static uint32_t ldr_filtered;
  static bool relay;

  uint16_t const ldr_raw = analogRead(ldrPin);
  ldr_filtered = (ldr_raw * IIR_new + ldr_filtered * IIR_old) / IIR_full_scale;

  relay = ldr_filtered > threshold_with_hyst[relay];
  auto pin = relay ? HIGH : LOW;
  digitalWrite(ledPin, pin);
  digitalWrite(relayPin, pin);
}
```

The IIR produces rather reasonable assembly. The division gets executed as shifts:

```
; this is an excerpt
    mov r19,r18  ;  ldr_raw, high
    mov r18,r24  ;  ldr_raw, low
.LVL61:
.LBE40:
.LBE41:
 ;  sketch_jul01a.ino:40:   ldr_filtered = (ldr_raw * IIR_new + ldr_filtered * IIR_old) / IIR_full_scale;
    .loc 4 40 0
    ldi r26,lo8(-32)     ; ,
    ldi r27,lo8(40)  ; ,
    call __umulhisi3
    movw r12,r22     ;  tmp176,
    movw r14,r24     ; ,
    lds r18,_ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered  ;  ldr_filtered, ldr_filtered
    lds r19,_ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered+1    ;  ldr_filtered, ldr_filtered
    lds r20,_ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered+2    ;  ldr_filtered, ldr_filtered
    lds r21,_ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered+3    ;  ldr_filtered, ldr_filtered
    ldi r26,lo8(-71)     ; ,
    ldi r27,lo8(126)     ; ,
    call __muluhisi3
    movw r26,r24     ; ,
    movw r24,r22     ;  tmp181, tmp178
.LVL62:
    add r24,r12  ;  tmp181, tmp176
    adc r25,r13  ; ,
    adc r26,r14  ; ,
    adc r27,r15  ; ,
    ldi r18,15   ; ,
    1:
    lsr r27  ;  _62
    ror r26  ;  _62
    ror r25  ;  _62
    ror r24  ;  _62
    dec r18  ; 
    brne 1b
    sts _ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered,r24  ;  ldr_filtered, _62
    sts _ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered+1,r25    ;  ldr_filtered, _62
    sts _ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered+2,r26    ;  ldr_filtered, _62
    sts _ZZ4loopE12ldr_filtered+3,r27    ;  ldr_filtered, _62
```